# Document Set Document has Different Permissions

Tags: 2013, workflow, document-set, item-level-permissions

I have a Document Library with one Document Set Content Type.  When a new Document Set is created I run a Workflow that changes the permissions on the Document Set to specific users.  This all works well.

However, when one of the users, who isn't the owner of the document set, but has rights to edit it, uploads a file to it, the file isn't visible to the document owner.

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening or how to resolve it?

Comment: Is checking required on the library/versioning?

Comment: No, it isn't.  I can put together a Workflow that will Grant permissions on the file so they match the overall document library permissions for the new file. I can't seem to write one that will actually just give the file the same permissions as the Document Set the Document belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

If Check-in / out is enabled in the library then no one but the uploader will be able to see the document until it is checked-in.

Comment: Good idea, but that isn't the case unfortunately.